# How To Load A Local File as an AssetBundle with WWW

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, load

So I have been trying to make it possible for users to load a .obj file and read it as an AssetBundle, but I can't figure it out.

I have figured out how to get the path of the file, but I can't load it as an asset bundle, it just returns null.

Here is my code :

```
        WWW bundleRequest = new WWW(@"file://" + pathName);

        while (!bundleRequest.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        AssetBundle bundle = null;
        if (bundleRequest.bytesDownloaded > 0)
        {
            AssetBundleCreateRequest myRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromMemoryAsync(bundleRequest.bytes);
            while (!myRequest.isDone)
            {
                Debug.Log("loading....");
                yield return null;
            }
            if (myRequest.assetBundle != null)
            {
                bundle = myRequest.assetBundle;
                GameObject model = null;
                if (bundle != null)
                {
                    AssetBundleRequest newRequest = bundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>("Test");
                    while (!newRequest.isDone)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("loading ASSET....");
                        yield return null;
                    }
                    model = (GameObject)newRequest.asset;

                    bundle.Unload(false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("COULDN'T DOWNLOAD ASSET BUNDLE FROM URL");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("COULDN'T DOWNLOAD ASSET BUNDLE FROM URL");
        }
```

`pathName` here is: `"C:\\Users\\mySuperCoolName\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Fun\\Programming\\Ungoing projects\\ThiefCop\\Unity Mobile\\Assets\\Prefabs\\TestOBJ.obj"`. Everything seems to work until `AssetBundleCreateRequest` when `AssetBundle.LoadFromMemoryAsync()` is called, where `myRequest.assetBundle == null` even if the file was *downloaded* correctly.

I also get an error which probably is linked with my problem : [image: Error]
 I have searched for what it meant but I couldn't find...

It is really hard to explain what I mean, but I really hope you can find an answer to this, I've been searching for hours and between us, I don't understand much of File loadind and Reading... 
Don't hesitate to ask if you didn't understand my bad english... 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you try using [UnityWebResquest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-DownloadingAssetBundle.html) instead of `WWW`?

Comment: A obj file can‘t be loaded directly as asset bundle. It needs to be built into an asset bundle file.

Comment: @JeanLuc Thank you for you're answer. I did think it had something to do with this but I didn't know how to code it. What is the code to do this please?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles.html

To be short :

- Import your object in Unity
- Give it a AssetBundle name (click on it then on bottom of the inspector view)
- Call this function

Comment: Could you please put some code, I really don't understand how to do this. Thank you

Comment: All I really want to do is Instantiate a .obj file stored on the computer, maybe I'm going completely in the wrong direction here.

Comment: The only lines of code you need is the first example in the link I gave to you.

- You import your object in Unity (basically you put it in your project)

- You click on your object in Project.

- You have a Asset Bundle Menu who should appear on the bottom of the Inspector view

- Just put a name and call the fonction from the link

Comment: But thays not what I want... I want to be able to instantaite a. obj file while the game is running with a path the user has chosen. Do you reckon this is possible? @Blue007422

Comment: Ok, so AssetBundle is not he way to do it and I don't know if it's actually possible to do it sorry

Answer (score 0):

for load obj files directly to you project, you need todo code what unpacks object file and then converts it to the Unity engine.

in assert store look at the Runtime OBJ Importer,
this should be right direction for your issue.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/runtime-obj-importer-49547