# Instantiating an Imported locally stored .obj File

Tags: file, unity-game-engine, import, load, instantiation

As you may have understood from the title of my question, I am trying to Instantiate a .obj file that is locally stored on the device with an already given path.

I have already tried to load it as an `assetBundle` using the `WWW` method, but it didn't work. I asked a question before on this forum (see here: [How To Load A Local File as an AssetBundle with WWW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54562488/how-to-load-a-local-file-as-an-assetbundle-with-www)), but I thought that maybe I was going completely in the wrong direction to do this, maybe there is another way to do it. Some people responded that I needed to *build the asset* before Instantiating it but I didn't understand.

I was hoping for any suggestions on how to do this

Than you in advance :)

*For more information, please see other question*: [How To Load A Local File as an AssetBundle with WWW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54562488/how-to-load-a-local-file-as-an-assetbundle-with-www)

Answer (score 0):

Related serialization data is generated when the asset is imported into Unity. And Unity needs these serialization information when managing these assets, so you can import the obj file into the Unity editor, create an assetbundle, and then load it through the associated api.
You can refer to this document:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html